# Chrome download API: default location for the save as window

Tags: google-chrome-extension, download, save-as

On my Chrome extension I have an option to download a file on a specific path (set by the user) but I've seen that is impossible to download a file outside the download directory, so I decided to use the `save as` option but when the dialog opens it is on the download directory but I want it to be on the folder previously chosen by the user

Comment: Not possible, https://crbug.com/838952.

Comment: And using another API?

Comment: There's no other API but you can use [nativeMessaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/nativeMessaging) and invoke a separate utility (which you can write in node.js for example) that will have the full access to file system.